# Controller redirection on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

I have a simple question I can't solve :

In my RoR controller, I have the classical

`format.html {redirect_to @document, notice= 'Document was successfully created.'}`

But I want to redirect this into a particular page: for example something like

```
redirect_to /page/document/:id_document
```

Do you have the exact syntax to do that ? Thank you !

Comment: try `redirect_to [:page, @document]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run **`rake routes`** in your terminal which will show you path or url helper methods according to your routes something like

```
your_helper GET    /page/document/:id_document     {:action=>"action_name", :controller=>"controller_name"}
```

then do

```
format.html {redirect_to your_helper_path(@document), notice= 'Document was successfully created.'}
```

**OR**

You can also use rails polymorphic url like `@jvnill` suggested

```
format.html {redirect_to [:page, @document], notice= 'Document was successfully created.'}
```